# How does one move files to a specific folder after an FTP download using PHP?

Tags: php, ftp

Is there a way to move files to a specific folder or declare a specific folder to download files by using `FTP` methods in `PHP`?

In short, I am downloading 10,000+ files and I want them to go into a certain folder that I already created. I am using an `FTP` connection to download the files from my script and I am looping through every file in the `FTP` server. They all download (and it takes a hell of a long time) - I just need to declare a specific path or move the files to the folder.

Here is the code:

```
 function ftp_sync($dir, $conn_id){
   if($dir !== '.'){
     if(ftp_chdir($conn_id, $dir) === FALSE){
       echo 'Change directory failed: ' . $dir . PHP_EOL;
   return;
 }
 chdir($dir);
}
 $contents = ftp_nlist($conn_id, '.');
 foreach($contents as $file){
 if($file == '.' || $file == '..'){
   continue;
 }
 if(@ftp_chdir($conn_id, $file)){
   ftp_chdir($conn_id, "..");
   ftp_sync($file, $conn_id);
 } else {
   ftp_get($conn_id, $file, $file, FTP_BINARY);
   //TODO: Download the files into a specific directory
 }
}
 ftp_chdir($conn_id, '..');
 chdir('..');
}

$ftp_server    = 'server';
$user          = 'user';
$password      = 'password';
$document_root = '/';
$sync_path     = 'Web_Images';
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);
if ($conn_id) {
  $login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $user, $password);
ftp_pasv($conn_id, true);
if ($login_result) {
    ftp_chdir($conn_id, $document_root);
    ftp_sync($sync_path, $conn_id);
    ftp_close($conn_id);
} else {
    echo 'login to server failed!' . PHP_EOL;
}
} else {
 echo 'connection to server failed!';
}
echo 'done.' . PHP_EOL;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ftp_get($conn_id, $file, $file, FTP_BINARY);` should be able to place your remote file anywhere you want as a default, you just have to indicate that spot in the local parameter:

```
# Where ever you want to download local files to
$dir = __DIR__.'/my/specific/path/';
# See if directory exists, create if not
if(!is_dir($dir))
    mkdir($dir,0755,true);
# Saves the file(s) into the $dir folder with the same name as the remote file
ftp_get($conn_id, $dir.$file, $file, FTP_BINARY);
```

Comment: Many thanks! This works, but then I realized it wasn't feasible to do this for the number of files I was trying to download (which was over 10K separate images) - this works great for much smaller amounts!

Comment: You could probably do it, but you’d have to make the execution time on the script almost infinite so it didn’t time out.